# how to add custom attribute in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel and I want to add dynamic custom attribute in controller

I know there is a way like this

```
      public function getFullNameAttribute()
        {
            return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
        }
```

now you can get full name as:

```
    $user = User::find(1);
    $user->full_name;
```

but it is in Model
I want to declare custom att in controller
is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do it in the controller? It makes more sense in the model and this 'magic method' is only supported in the Model

Comment: @Christophe Hubert because I want to pass dynamic att for each record ( for example related Items ) and I find related Items in controller

Comment: I would recommend to still keep it in the Model and then use a custom accessor that accept arguments: `getFullNameWithExtra($extra) {...}`

Comment: why would a controller need "attributes"?

Comment: I'm not sure you're making your use case clear here. As you mentioned, this can be done in the model. Can you provide an example of what you're trying achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Why not in model? Eloquent has a great feature called “Accessors”. The feature allows you to add custom fields to models that don’t exist on the model or in the table.

```
function getFullNameAttribute() {
    return sprintf('%s %s', $this->first_name, $this->last_name);
}
```

Now you have access to a full_name attribute on the model, same as you mentioned:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->full_name;
```